# is List.forEach ordered in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I googled this and also tried to find documentation about it but failed to do so.

Question is simple.
I have a `List` let's say foo. if I do

`foo.forEach(this::doSomething)`
and use the same line again for the same `foo` would I have the order of the iteration same each time?

If yes, what about `foo.stream().forEach()`?

Comment: It'd be pretty weird if the order of iteration of a sequential data structure wasn't... sequential.

Comment: General rule with libraries: if it's not explicitly documented, then don't expect it to behave as you think or consistently at all.

Answer (score 19):

`forEach` is defined in `Iterable` and the Javadoc says:

> Unless otherwise specified by the implementing class,
>   actions are performed in the order of iteration (if an iteration order
>   is specified).

Now `List.iterator()` says:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.

So by default you should expect that `forEach` enumerates the elements in proper sequence - unless an list implementation has a differing iterator implementation.

---

According `Stream.forEach` the Javadoc tells you that you should not rely on an order:

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic. For
>   parallel stream pipelines, this operation does *not* guarantee
>   to respect the encounter order of the stream, as doing so would
>   sacrifice the benefit of parallelism.

but there is also `Stream.forEachOrdered`:

> Performs an action for each element of this stream, in the encounter
>   order of the stream if the stream has a defined encounter order.

Comment: sorry but in that case `parallelStream().forEach()` would also return in sequence?